# Mocking AOP method implementation for unit tests

Tags: spring, unit-testing

I've a java application which has multiple modules - (GWT-)RPC services, `perf-library`, `remote-client` (All java code written/owned by my team). The `perf-library` contains Spring AOP aspects related code and it's primarily used to push intercepted method logs to a data store. Now, `perf-library` is dependent on another remote-client which actually maintains a queue and handles the job of pushing logs to the data store. So, in a way, `perf-library` just delegates the task to remote-client. 
The business logic code calls intercepted methods which have AOP logic and hence there is a dependency on remote-client. Obviously, I don't want to connect to the remote-client from within unit tests. I think I need to mock the implementation of method `push()` which connects to remote-client. What I'm unable to figure out is how to use the mock implementation for the business logic code package unit tests.

To clarify things, I've modules like this -

- `RPC service module` - e.g. method `login()` is intercepted.
- `perf-library` - Has aspects (to intercept methods like `login()`) and implementation to call `remote-client`
- `remote-client` - Push data to some data-store

Now, for writing the unit tests for RPC service methods, how do I get the mock implementation of `push()` as it is internal to perf-library. Let's say, I've an interface `LogClient` (having method `push()`) which is implemented by two classes (one for production and another for test). I can use this Test implementation for unit tests of perf-library itself, but how do I make the RPC unit tests use it. I'm new to Spring, so not sure if this can be done easily with Spring or anything else. Any help will be nice.

Note: We're using Spring for maintaining beans and DI.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly how but [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) can be a good choice.
Check this [link](http://tamasgyorfi.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/mocking-tutorial-part-2-mockito/) for details.

Comment: I've heard about mocking libraries such as Mockito, but can you explain a bit in detail? How do I inject the mock implementation and use that in a different library?

Comment: @SwapnilS: I have added link in my answer.